# Iterating the rows and running Python with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to separately run each row from 1 column in a spreadsheet using openpyxl

It works fine as far as bringing all row values

But I'm having issues running all the rows (2-9) through the code to give results for each row

What works (brings in values for rows 2 through 9)

What doesn't work (only runs the last row 9)

```
import openpyxl
import re

path =r"./reviews.xlsx"

file =openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheet =file.active

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,max_row=9,min_col=1,max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
        txt =(cell.value)

a = re.findall(r”\b(meatballs|meat ball)\b”, txt, re.IGNORECASE)
if a:

    a1 = re.findall(r”\b(meatballs|meat ball)(?:\W+\w+){0,9}?\W+(good|great)\b|\b(good|great)(?:\W+\w+){0,9}?\W+(meatballs|meat ball)\b", txt, re.IGNORECASE)
    if a1:
        print(“positive review for meatballs“)
```

Comment: The way your indentation is, only the last value for 'txt' (row9) is ever searched since the loop does not proceed to the **a = re.findall...** line until after the row/cell iteration completes. If you want to check each cell value for the search item(s) you need to move those lines into the row/cell loop.

Comment: Thank you that worked!! Now I can start figuring out how to write the results back to the spreadsheet :)